# Google chart multiple series with same scale

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm looking for a way to have multiple series on my graphics, with the same scales but displayed only once.

as you can see here : 
http://jsfiddle.net/Youkoal/d3xwnqdu/ 
I have 4 séries and the chart display all 4 axis.

I have noted that this properties do not seem to work here:

```
TextStyle: {color: 'none'}
```

nor

```
{format: 'none'}
```

when included in the axis options.

How can I 'hide' those axis or put all series on same scales?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the first letter in `textStyle` should be lowercase...

```
    textStyle: {
      color: 'none'
    }
```

this will hide the text, but the chart will still allocate room for the labels,
to minimize, reduce the `fontSize`...

```
    textStyle: {
      color: 'none',
      fontSize: 1
    }
```

ideally we could use `textPosition: 'none'`, but this option is not supported for *material* charts.
[Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['bar']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Semaines', 'Test Region', 'Test2 Region', 'Test SerieNE', 'Test2 SerieNE', 'Test SerieS', 'Test2 SerieS', 'Test SerieO', 'Test2 SerieO'],
    ['Semaine 1', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    ['Semaine 2', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    ['Semaine 3', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    ['Semaine 4', 24, 0, 21, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0],
    ['Semaine 5', 122, 0, 21, 0, 52, 0, 49, 0],
    ['Semaine 6', 361, 0, 23, 0, 325, 0, 13, 0],
    ['Semaine 7', 51, 0, 21, 0, 11, 0, 19, 0],
    ['Semaine 8', 81, 3, 3, 0, 64, 3, 14, 0],
    ['Semaine 9', 711, 22, 81, 3, 527, 9, 103, 10],
    ['Semaine 10', 139, 13, 26, 5, 104, 5, 9, 3],
    ['Semaine 11', 255, 12, 139, 2, 33, 4, 83, 6],
    ['Semaine 12', 256, 10, 23, 4, 15, 5, 218, 1],
    ['Semaine 13', 145, 26, 84, 7, 58, 16, 3, 3],
    ['Semaine 14', 112, 15, 51, 0, 34, 11, 27, 4],
    ['Semaine 15', 122, 27, 29, 8, 53, 14, 40, 5],
    ['Semaine 16', 98, 18, 17, 6, 31, 7, 50, 5],
    ['Semaine 17', 87, 21, 12, 6, 37, 3, 38, 12],
  ]);

  var options = {
    chart: {
      title: 'Suivis hebdo',
      subtitle: 'Pilotage',
    },
    bars: 'vertical',
    isStacked: true,
    height: 600,
    series: {
      2: {
        targetAxisIndex: 1
      },
      3: {
        targetAxisIndex: 1
      },
      4: {
        targetAxisIndex: 2
      },
      5: {
        targetAxisIndex: 2
      },
      6: {
        targetAxisIndex: 3
      },
      7: {
        targetAxisIndex: 3
      }
    },
    vAxis: {
      format: 'decimal',
      viewWindow: {
        min: 0,
        max: 1000
      }
    },
    vAxes: {
      1: {
        textStyle: {
          color: 'none',
          fontSize: 1
        }
      },
      2: {
        textStyle: {
          color: 'none',
          fontSize: 1
        }
      },
      3: {
        textStyle: {
          color: 'none',
          fontSize: 1
        }
      }
    },
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

notes:

1) need to use the correct library, `jsapi` should no longer be used, instead use `loader.js`
this will only change the `load` statement, see above snippet...

2) you can use option `vAxis` to set the scale for all `vAxes`

3) it isn't necessary to move the first series to another `targetAxisIndex`