# Remove Y Axis and its grid lines

Tags: reactjs, charts, google-visualization, react-google-charts

Im using `react-google-charts`

This is my chart code

```js
<Chart
  chartType="Bar"
  loader={<div>Loading Chart</div>}
  data={[
    ["", "Credit", "Debit"],
    [
      "AVERAGE",
      avg_credit,
      avg_debit,
    ],
    [
      "30 Days",
      sum_values[0].CREDIT,
      sum_values[0].DEBIT,
    ],
    [
      "60 Days",
      sum_values[1].CREDIT,
      sum_values[1].DEBIT,
    ],
    [
      "90 Days",
      sum_values[2].CREDIT,
      sum_values[2].DEBIT,
    ],
  ]}
  options={{
    legend: { position: "none" },
    hAxis: {
      baselineColor: "none",
      ticks: [],
    },
  }}
/>
```

I have added the hAxis option there because I would like to completely remove the Y-axis (It's bar, it's numbering, and it's grid lines going horizontally through the graph), but they don't seem to have any effect, what can I do to achieve it? Thanks

Comment: given `"Bar"` is a _material_ chart, the `ticks` option is [not supported](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143) -- does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50061663/5090771) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It will remove axis and text of that axis

```
hAxis: { textPosition: "none", gridlines: { count: 0 } },
  vAxis: { textPosition: "none", gridlines: { count: 0 } },
  baselineColor:"transparent",
```